# How long Youtube Video was Watched for?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Can anyone help me for getting the time in seconds of a youtube video that was watched?

Comment: are you embedding the video on your site?

Comment: yes i'm, when the user clicks on video play button then video has to play and when the user clicks on the video close button then it has to record the time in seconds (how long it was watched for). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your YouTube analytics it should provide you with data such as this, unfortunately there is no tracking aspect of it on Google Analytics unless you just want to track the number of views through goal/event tracking.